# Printing a Continuous Curve - MatplotLib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to implement a neural network in Python, and I want to plot the cost per iteration.

Here is what my current code looks like -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for i in range(50000):

    if (i % 500 == 0):
        y = np.random.random()  # Cost Function.
        ax.scatter(i, y, label ='Cost')

plt.show()
```

Here is the output -

[image: Plot of Y vs X]

#### Problem

The plot does not show one continuous curve. Instead, it shows different points in different colours depicting the `(i, y)` tuple at each iteration.

Also, the 'Label' is being printed on the legend for 100 times, which obviously is not what I want.

I am trying to print a continuous curve, and one legend.

I have tried `ax.plot()` instead of `ax.scatter()`, but it does not work.

Can someone please help? I am new to Python, and I am sure I am missing out something basic. I have tried searching for the answer in Google, but I am not getting anything definite.

Thanks !

Comment: Use this: `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

x = []
y = []
for i in range(50000):
    if (i % 500 == 0):
        y.append(np.random.random())
        x.append(i)
ax.plot(x, y, '-', label ='Cost')
plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `scatter` will always plot points.  The `plot` function had a large selection of parameters (including the ability to plot points) with the default as plotting line segments between pairs of points.  Feeding `plot` a single point `x, y` at each step in a `for` loop such as:

```
for x,y in zip(range(10), range(10)):
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

will not show anything.  This is because matplotlib is trying to draw a line between each of the input value of `x` and `y`.  Since only one value is passed at each step, it is drawing a line from `(x,y)` to `(None, None)`, resulting in no line at all.

To plot a continuous line, you need to collect all of your coordinate pairs into an iterable (list, array, etc), and pass them to `plot`.

```
x = []
y = []
for i in range(50000):
    if (i % 500 == 0):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(np.random.random())  # Cost Function.
ax.plot(x, y, label ='Cost')
```